# setcookie HTTP 500 error

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone could catch what is wrong with my php code, for setting a cookie. Thanks!

```
    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
    $selected_image = $_GET["img"];
    $selected_caption = $_GET["caption"];
    $selected_color = $_GET["color"];

    switch ($selected_image){
        case:"img1"
            setcookie("img1_caption", $selected_caption, $expire);
            setcookie("img1_color", $selected_color, $expire);
            break;
        case:"img2"
            setcookie("img2_caption", $selected_caption, $expire);
            setcookie("img2_color", $selected_color, $expire);
            break;
        case:"img3"
            setcookie("img3_caption", $selected_caption, $expire);
            setcookie("img3_color", $selected_color, $expire);      
            break;
        case:"img4"
            setcookie("img4_caption", $selected_caption, $expire);
            setcookie("img4_color", $selected_color, $expire);          
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. The `:` goes after the value. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

```
switch ($selected_image){
    case "img1":
        setcookie("img1_caption", $selected_caption, $expire);
        setcookie("img1_color", $selected_color, $expire);
        break;
    case "img2":
        setcookie("img2_caption", $selected_caption, $expire);
        setcookie("img2_color", $selected_color, $expire);
        break;
    case "img3":
        setcookie("img3_caption", $selected_caption, $expire);
        setcookie("img3_color", $selected_color, $expire);      
        break;
    case "img4":
        setcookie("img4_caption", $selected_caption, $expire);
        setcookie("img4_color", $selected_color, $expire);          
        break;
}
```

Comment: Haha thanks I feel stupid!